Jupyter notebook function not updated in the execution
I have a jupyter notebook cell as shown below. Each time I make modification to the reshape_transform function, the modification will be ignored when executing the cell. I have to restart kernel every time to make the modifcation effective. How can I execute this cell without needing to restart the kernel?
I did some searches. Most searches propose to use importlib.reload. But in my case, the modfication is not in the external file but the function defined in Jupyter cell. I also tested %load_ext autoreload and %autoreload 2. But the issue remains.
import pytorch_grad_cam as pgc


def reshape_transform(tensor, height=14, width=14):
    result = tensor[1:, :, :, :]
    result = result.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
    return result

def run(model, target_layers)
    cam = pgc.GradCAM(
        model=model,
        target_layers=target_layers,
        reshape_transform=reshape_transform
    )

run(model, target_layers)

I want to execute this cell without needing to restart the kernel.

Does this code actually run? def run(model, target_layers) and the next few lines doesn't look like legit code to me. Did you already try breaking up the cell more? For example, this looks like it should be three cells. "But in my case, the modfication is not in the external file but the function defined in Jupyter cell." I'm thinking you aren't quite correct about that. You maybe trying to supplant the function it normally uses with yours and so you maybe affecting the namespace made by that import. I may be wrong on that. Part of the confusion is your code look syntactically incorrect. ...

 Anyway, it looks like you are better off reloading the import. Not sure why the methods involving importlib wouldn't be working. Minor: Your post title needs work. Please read How do I ask a good question?, paying particular attention to the section under 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'. A good way to think about it would be to imagine a long list of post titles and write a title that would most help you identify the one you need from that list.

Thank you for the suggestion, I updated the question title. @Wayne Can you please elaborate on why the code look syntactically incorrect? The code snippet does miss model, it is not very related to the question, so I do not put it here. One example would be import timm; model = timm.create_model('resnet34').

I am used to a function being defined like you have for reshape_transform(). Look closely at the syntax. Or better yet, actually run the code you've shared in a new notebook. It will give SyntaxError: expected ':' Is there a minimal, reproducible example you can share? Hopefully it is minor and someone familiar with your code will better understand you aren't providing real code here. The bigger question here is why can't you use importlib to reload pytorch_grad_cam?
